# Change variable in handlebars context

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I can't get the value of a variable in handlebars context after I change the variable. I think it's a closur problem but I don't know how to get around this.
I have a index.html file which include links to different .js files.

```
// index.html
</head>
// links to jquery, handlebars etc.
    <script src="src\js\Renders.js"></script>
    <script src="src\js\ImageData.js"></script>
    <script src="src\js\app.page1.js"></script>
    <script src="src\js\app.page2.js"></script> 
</head>
// ....
```

All of my script files are writen as revealing module patterns. They include a html string, context/data for handlebars and DOM-methods. In Render.js, I have a simple function to render the templates

```
var Render = (function() {
    const render = function(template, context, target) {
        let compile = Handlebars.compile(template);
        target.html(compile(context));
    };

    return {
        render : render
    };
    })();
```

In ImageData, I store data, that is get buy user input.

```
var Images = (function() {
    let image_array =  [],
    image_data = {x:3};

    let addImage = function(fileList) {
        _.forEach(fileList, file => {
            if(!_.some(image_array, obj => obj.name === file.name)) {
               file.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
               image_array.push(file);
            }
        });
    };

    return {
        image_array             :   image_array,
        image_data              :   image_data,
        addImage                :   addImage            
    };
    })();
```

Now, on page1, I want to add values on the image_data obj like:

```
function() {
return IMG.image_data.width = 100;
}
```

When I console.log the obj, the value is set.

Now, on page2, Handlebars should take the new value from the obj and render it in the context.

```
var App = App || {};
App.settings = (function(IMG, XHB, $) {
    'use strict';

    const templates = {
      main : String()
        + '<main id="page">' //....
const context = {
        image_data : [
            { value : Images.image_data.width },  
            { value : Images.image_data.x}
        ];
    let initModule = function ( $target_container) {
        XHB.render(templates.main, context, $target_container);
        })
    };  
    return { initModule : initModule };
})(Images, Render, jQuery);
```

Handlebars get access to the x-variable, but never to the new variable "width".

Comment: What is `IMG` in page1.js? It looks like it should be `Images`.

Comment: IMG is the shortcut for Images. It is importet like on page2. This works fine.

Comment: The code snippet you are sharing for "page1" is not valid syntax.

Comment: Please describe why? I think the problem is not about a syntax error because with console.log I can see, that the value of Images.image_data.width is set to 100 after the function call. I think the problem is, that on the first load, when the IIFE is run, the value of "width" is undefined. This undefined value is passed to the Handlebars compile context. So how can I call the XHB.render method after the value of "width" has changed from undefined to 100.

Comment: Why don't you add some `console.log`s and ensure that `100` is assigned to Images.image_data.width before you initialize your `context` object?

Comment: I think that's the problem, because the context is passed to Handlebars as the IIFE is immediately invoked and at this point the value is undefined. Until I get the user input, the value is set to 100.